# MS Access: If option button is selected, use a criteria, otherwise return all rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, criteria, ms-access-2016

I have a table with a field called `job`. I have a form with an option button. If the option button is ***not*** selected, I want to return all rows. However, if the option button ***is*** selected, I want to return all rows that do ***not*** begin with "RWK". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE Forms!myForm!myOptionButton.Value = 0 
   OR job NOT LIKE 'RWK*'
```

Boolean logic. If the option button is off, the WHERE clause is always true.